# Gesetzliche/Rechtliche Regulierung der/von Wirtschaft

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german

I am struggling how to translate "**Legal Regulation of Economics**".

Which one is correct?

**Gesetzliche/Rechtliche Regulierung der/von Wirtschaft**

Comment: This is to inform you that you question has been put on hold. To have it reopened, change your question to ask only about one of your two concerns (and ask a separate question about the other if you like). Please also elaborate your understanding so far as it allows us to better understand your problems and to give you more helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Gesetzliche Regulierung der Wirtschaft
```

klingt am besten. Eine Alternative ist

```
Staatliche Regulierung der Wirtschaft
```

Sie betont, dass es der Staat ist, der in die Wirtschaft eingreift.